# Can I upgrade RAM on my HP Pavilion G7-1031eo?

Tags: windows-7, memory, hp-pavilion

I have 4 GB DDR3 RAM in my HP Pavilion G7-1031eo. I am running on it win 7 home premium x64.

My question is: can I add there another 4GB ram? I found different answers on this questions and I do not know what is true.

[Here](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c02776696&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=101&prodSeriesId=5048677&prodTypeId=321957) is that I can not. And [here](http://www.satech.com/hp-notebook-memory-hp-pavilion-notebook-memory-hp-pavilion-g-memory-hp-compaq-pavilion-g7-1031eo-mem.html) is I can upgrade it if I am running a x64 system (what I do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have agreed with the others and the lack of easily found HP docs. However, in HP's general specificaton doc of the G7 series, it says that there are 2 memory slots, with a limit of 4gb per slot or 8gb total. Its on page 3 of [this HP G7 document](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02720306.pdf), under "memory modules".

Answer (score 0):

HP indicates 4GB max but you can see if a BIOS upgrade may allow more.  It may also be that the larger SODIMM was not readily available and upgrade will work.  [Kingston](http://www.kingston.com/us/memory/search/Default.aspx?DeviceType=3&Mfr=HEW&Line=Pavilion%20Notebook&Model=71470) indicates that 6GB and 8GB are possible unless the chipset is based on Intel GL40  cannot tell from the spec if this is the case